# Кнопка не меняет цвет. BackgroundTint

Tags: android, button, background

Во время верстки приложения возникла проблема с цветом кнопки,а именно: я использую `android:backgroundTint` для установления оттенка. Дополню,что я использую это на двух активностях,при этом в одной все идеально,а во второй как раз и возникает эта проблема.[image: На втором скрине все выглядит как должно выглядеть]

[image: XML кнопок]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы используете библиотеку поддержки API 22,23,24 ... Вы можете использовать `android:backgroundTint` Если ваша минимальная API ниже 22 версии, она работать не будет. У себя решил эту проблему просто поставил фото `android:background="@drawable/foto"`, так как студия использует встроенные изображения. Можно и тут [посмотреть](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574328/changing-edittext-bottom-line-color-with-appcompat-v7).

Comment: Спасибо,помогли. [Вот](https://android-tools.ru/coding/delaem-krasivye-knopki-v-android/) нашел еще подробное создание кастомизированной кнопки,может и Вам пригодится.